# mvxspinner not change display value in my viewmodel

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a button to change my mvxspinner, but in my view model I can't change the value displayed in my mvxspinner. For Example :

I have the mvxspinner and button in a layout :

```
<MvxSpinner
      style="@style/SpinnerField.Filter"
      android:id="@+id/filter_listacliente_spinner_bairro"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ListaBairro;SelectedItem FiltroBairro;"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/filter_spinner_bairro"
      local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/filter_item_spinner_bairro" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/filter_listacliente_btlimpar"
        android:theme="@style/DefaultButton"
        local:MvxBind="Click LimparFiltros" 
        style="@style/DefaultButtonFilter"/>
```

In my `ICommand`, I tried changing my value to "Estado" and ID to "-1":

```
public ICommand LimparFiltros
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() =>
        {

            FiltroEstado = new EstadoDto { IdEstado = -1, Descricao = "Estado" };

        });
    }
}
```

My `SelectedItem` :

```
var _filtroEstado = new EstadoDto();
public EstadoDto FiltroEstado
{
    get { return _filtroEstado; }
    set
    {
        _filtroEstado = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => FiltroEstado);
    }
}
```

**Result for this:** Nothing change in my display :(.

**Expected result:** My display have a description "Estado" selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing the backing field `_filtroEstado` which will not cause the `RaisePropertyChanged` in your `FiltroEstado` property set to fire an `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. So the view with never get notified of the change.

> `return new MvxCommand(() =>
>   {
>       _filtroEstado = new EstadoDto { IdEstado = -1, Descricao = "Estado" };
>   });`

Additionally, the reference for the `SelectedItem` needs to come form the bound `ItemsSource` list. Therefore, you could do something like:

```
return new MvxCommand(() =>
{
    FiltroBairro = ListaBairro.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdEstado == -1);
});
```

Comment: I changed my question, i not used _filtroEstado to set values

Comment: @user1875730 The issue is that you are setting the `SelectedItem` to an object reference that does not exist with the `ListaBairro` i.e. your `ItemsSource`. See the additional comment in my answer above. The `SelectedItem` needs to exist within the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: debuggin my ViewModel, find this Warn > "MvxBind:Warning:577.84 Value not found for spinner JWRConsultoria.AFV.JForce.Core.Application.Dtos.EnderecoDto"

Comment: Yip, if you want to have a new item selected, you will first need to add it to your list that is bound to the `ItemsSource` before setting it as the `SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your private variable, `_filtroEstado`, inside `LimparFiltros`. As a result, the `set` on the public `FiltroEstado` property isn't firing, and neither is the `RaisePropertyChanged`.

Comment: Srry, i changed my question